# Ingest base64 encoded avro messages in druid

Tags: base64, avro, druid

I want to ingest base64 encoded avro messages in druid. I am getting the following error -

`Avro's unnecessary EOFException, detail: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-813`

Going through the code (line 88) https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/master/extensions-core/avro-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/druid/data/input/avro/InlineSchemaAvroBytesDecoder.java , it does not seem to be decoding the messages using base64 decoder. Am I missing something? How can we configure druid to parse base64 encoded avro messages?

Spec used -

```
"inputFormat": {
        "type": "avro_stream",
        "avroBytesDecoder": {
          "type": "schema_inline",
          "schema": {
            "namespace": "org.apache.druid.data",
            "name": "User",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "price",
                "type": "int"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "flattenSpec": {
          "useFieldDiscovery": true,
          "fields": [
            {
              "type": "path",
              "name": "someRecord_subInt",
              "expr": "$.someRecord.subInt"
            }
          ]
        },
        "binaryAsString": false
      }
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Avro ingestion, but from the Apache Druid [docs here](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/avro.html#binary-types) it seems like you need to set "binaryAsString" to true.

```
The extension returns bytes and fixed Avro types as base64 encoded strings by default. To decode these types as UTF-8 strings, enable the binaryAsString option on the Avro parser.
```

Comment: I did try the same. But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I could not find any existing solution for this, so I created a separate extension which is a copy of existing avro-extension. I just made the following changes in file `src/main/java/org/apache/druid/data/input/avro/InlineSchemaAvroBytesDecoder.java` and created the jar for the same and used in the setup-

```
try (ByteBufferInputStream inputStream = new ByteBufferInputStream(Collections.singletonList(bytes))) {
  return reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(inputStream, null));
}
```

to

```
try (ByteBufferInputStream inputStream = new ByteBufferInputStream(Collections.singletonList(Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes)))) {
      return reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(inputStream, null));
}
```